# How to debug Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I'm having an issue with a Heroku app. Using the logs from "Heroku Logs" are not helpful at all. Is there a way to access more detailed logs/info of why the app is crashing?

Thanks!

The error message I'm getting:

```
2016-06-28T20:09:15.992921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/register" host=serene-falls-82083.herokuapp.com request_id=47a611d6-b762-4efb-b3ba-b9dcb856287f fwd="99.126.142.177" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

My App set up:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://LINK.mlab.com");



app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');






app.set("view-engine", "ejs");
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(flash());




// //PASSPORT CONFIG
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "H.",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
   res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
   res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
   next();
});
```

Comment: What error are you seeing when it crashes? When it crashes does the process stop completely? What logs is heroku showing you? You might need to increase the logging in your application so that it dumps the necessary info into heroku logs

Comment: Did you check for console errors in the browser when pulling up the app url? Does it run locally?

Comment: It works perfectly locally. I added some more info. Zero console errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like some part of your request just takes too long so basically it's not crashing you just have to profile and figure out the bottleneck. You might want to use external services that profile and capture stack traces like [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/) or [New Relic](http://newrelic.com).